# elasticsearchについて

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

elasticsearchをダウンロードした後についてエラーで止まっております。
どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

現状の状態
elasticsearchコマンドを入力するとelasticsearchが立ち上がりましたが、
`bundle exec rake search_index:create_and_import` コマンドを入力するとエラーになります

> rake aborted!
>
> Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [service]: The [string] type is removed in 5.0 and automatic upgrade failed because parameters [boost] are not supported for automatic upgrades. You should now use either a [text] or [keyword] field instead for field [name]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [service]: The [string] type is removed in 5.0 and automatic upgrade failed because parameters [boost] are not supported for automatic upgrades. You should now use either a [text] or [keyword] field instead for field [name]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The [string] type is removed in 5.0 and automatic upgrade failed because parameters [boost] are not supported for automatic upgrades. You should now use either a [text] or [keyword] field instead for field [name]"}},"status":400}

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました
ver 1-5-2でinstallすれば完了しました

Comment: お疲れ様です。よければ、同じ現象で悩んでいる方のために、質問を編集して元々のバージョンを追記していただけませんか？

Answer (score 0):

同じ現象で、`gemfile` に
`gem 'elasticsearch', '2.4.1'` を書いて

`bundle update elasticsearch` で
`Could not find gem 'elasticsearch (= 2.4.1)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.` と言われます。

どうすればよろしいでしょうか。